# RegEx - Exclude random String between specific tags

Tags: regex

I have to change a lot of tags in an XML-Document and think RegEx might be the best solution for this, but I can't figure out the correct snytax:

```
<tag1 attribute="value1">random content1<tag1>
<tag1 attribute="value2">random content2<tag1>
<tag1 attribute="value1">random content3<tag1>
```

This is the current state. "tag1" can have different values for "attribute" at the moment. The new structure gets rid of those combinations, but instead uses specific elements for that.

```
<tag1 attribute="value1">random content1<tag1>
<!-- tag1 + value1 requires <tag2>random content1</tag2> : -->
<tag2>random content1<tag2>

<tag1 attribute="value2">random content2<tag1>
<!-- tag1 + value2 requires <tag3>random content2</tag3> : -->
<tag3>random content1<tag3>
```

I need to change all of those tag->attribute-combinations without touching the content inbetween. Is it possible to select those specific tags while excluding their contents?
Help is very appreciated!

Comment: Oh boy, it's *this* question again...

Comment: [You should not try to parse SGML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6320039)

Comment: [TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610) ... Have you tried using an XML parser instead?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Vr9BjI/1 like that?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I looked into that solution. The content itself changes during the substitution (or maybe I missunderstood something)

Comment: @Vinik No it doesn't. What do you think changed?

Comment: @YassinHajaj The tags (as needed) and the content. But I have to change the tags only *shrugs*